# Where to find .mxd examples for ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, mxd

I'm trying to learn how to use ArcMap.

I would like to find some example MXD files for ArcMap, but couldn't find anything googling.

Does anyone know where I can find any MXD samples for ArcGIS 10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ESRI ArcGIS Resources page for Local Goverment](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/local-government/) has several sample maps that are available for download.  The download includes the mxd and all associated data in a file geodatabase.  I would say download the [Tax Parcel Map Book](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d87e8c1ec71a46ac94b8ab694430a429) and the [Campus Editing](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4eb4cb3f42fd4af699a0d76cf91834b0) samples as places to start.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to learn ArcMap I think searching its online help for tutorials will be your best starting point.

An MXD file on its own does not contain spatial data so a search for map packages *.mpk (MXD + spatial data) may prove more productive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) Appreciate the help considering my newbie question ;) sorry I would give you +1, but my reputation doesn't allow it

Comment: I can! And will. Good answer, I was about to say pretty much exactly the same thing but got ninja'd by both answerers :(

Answer (score 1):

have you come across this [lesson planner](http://esri.ca/en/resources/lesson-planner) for ArcGIS resources? It's targeted at teachers and profs, but a lot can be pulled from them as the majority are targeted at beginners.

Here is a [link](http://esri.ca/en/content/introduction-arcgis) to get started with ArcGIS software.

Answer (score 1):

Another great way to learn the software that many users are unaware of is to use [ArcTutor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00qn0000013t000000) (a set of tutorials with .mxd docs, GIS data, and tools) which is available for free for anyone who has obtained ArcGIS Desktop. Unfortunately, you can download only some parts of ArcTutor on [ArcGIS.com](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6987d0a0daa14fe9861bae93e4808845); most of the tutorials are available only via [Esri Customer Care Portal](https://customers.esri.com/) which you as an Esri customer should have access to.

[Esri Training](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=search.results&searchterm=&search=Search&cannedsearch=2&OrderBy=) should also be a main entry point for anyone learning about Esri GIS technology. There are dozens of free web courses with the access to the training data (.mxd map documents, geodatabases, and tools). The tutorials are updated regularly and include the latest software versions.

[Esri ArcLessons](http://edcommunity.esri.com/Resources/ArcLessons/Search?q=&level=%7BC3621D2F-E338-4AEA-A611-25A12E7255AE%7D&topic=%7B31A3150B-60E9-4286-854A-6947D95A02ED%7D) web site has been quite popular for some years ago. They are not updated with the latest software technologies tutorials, but I find them very relevant particularly for the beginners. You will get understanding of various GIS concepts, not only how to use ArcMap.